# What's the API to get the top domain (root domain) from any domain in the hierarchy like tree or child domain?

Tags: powershell, adsi

What's the API to get the top domain (root domain) from any domain in the hierarchy like tree or child domain?

The closest I could find were `GetForest` or `GetCurrentForest` but that's not what I am looking for..

[[System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Forest]::GetForest(directorycontext)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.activedirectory.forest.getforest(v=vs.110).aspx)

[[System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Forest]::GetCurrentForest()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.activedirectory.forest.getcurrentforest(v=vs.110).aspx)

Thanks in advance,
-SunMan

Comment: "[...] that's not what I am looking for" - can you elaborate a bit? How does the information returned by `GetCurrentForest()` not satisfy your requirement?

Comment: sure.. Script is run by a user of forest A to find forest B. GetCurrentForest() gets a Forest object for the current user context ( the one who is logged in) and thus discovers Forest A everytime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get from a foreign domain name to its forest root domain, use [`Domain.GetDomain()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.activedirectory.domain.getdomain) first, then grab the root domain object through the `Forest` property:

```
$ForeignDomainDNS = 'other.domain.tld'
$ForeignDomainCtx = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.DirectoryContext 'Domain',$ForeignDomain
$ForeignDomain = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain]::GetDomain($ForeignDomainCtx)
$ForeignRootDomain = $ForeignDomain.Forest.RootDomain
```

`$ForeignRootDomain` now contains the `Domain` object representing the root domain of the foreign domain's forest

Comment: Nice.. I see the logic now and it works. Thanks @Mathias